# Stop button from being highlighted when clicked in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java-8, awt

I trying to get my JButton to stop its background change when clicked. I have been reading and testing answers from other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed) like [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543633/stopping-jbutton-highlighting-on-press) but none have helped me. I am very new to Java so specific details would be helpful, here is my code and a demonstration of what is happening. Also, I am running ubuntu if that matters at all.

Note: if I hold my mouse down and hover over it, it will also trigger the background change.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RaisedButton extends JButton{

    private String      text     =     "";
    private String      type     =     "default";


    public RaisedButton(String text, String type) {
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
        __init__();
    }

    private void foundations() {
        NotoFont noto = new NotoFont(true);
        this.setText(this.text.toUpperCase());
        this.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.setFont(noto.get());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(108 + this.text.length() * 4, 37));
    }

    private void default_type() {
        this.foundations();
        this.setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFFF"));
        this.setForeground(Color.decode("#000000"));
    }

    private void primary_type() {
        this.foundations();
        this.setBackground(Color.decode("#00BCD4"));
        this.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    private void secondary_type() {
        this.foundations();
        this.setBackground(Color.decode("#FF4081"));
        this.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    private void disabled_type() {
        this.foundations();
        this.setBackground(Color.decode("#E5E5E5"));
        this.setForeground(Color.decode("#B2A4A4"));
    }

    private void __init__() {
        switch(this.type.toLowerCase()) {
            case "default":
                default_type();
                break;
            case "primary":
                primary_type();
                break;
            case "secondary":
                secondary_type();
                break;
            case "disabled":
                disabled_type();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Demonstration of what's occurring...

[image: Demonstration]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting a custom [button- model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547218/3992939)  ?

Comment: THANKS! I tried it and it seemed to work this time. I must have just done something wrong with my previous attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FixedStateButtonModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543633/stopping-jbutton-highlighting-on-press/22547218#22547218) by adding 
`setModel(new FixedStateButtonModel());` to `foundations()` .

Answer (score 2):

Try put this in the RaisedButton constructor:

```
    setUI(new BasicButtonUI());
```

Answer (score 0):

Within you `foundations()` method, either change

```
this.setRolloverEnabled(true);
```

to set it false as:

```
this.setRolloverEnabled(false);
```

or remove the assignment to fallback to default value `false`

Details from the JavaDoc for [`setRolloverEnabled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Changed it but the issue is still occurring.

Comment: From the javadoc : "Some look and feels might not implement rollover effects; they will ignore this property."